# Error "Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm getting the error `Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`; I'm using MySQL.

Below is my trigger code:

```
delimiter |        
create trigger order_val after insert on tbl_order    
  for each row begin    
    call value(new.od_id,@e);    
    insert into od_val (od_id,od_val) values(new.od_id,@e);    
  end;    
|
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the trigger which leads to the message?  Is the error in response to an insert, or it is occurring when attempting to create the trigger?

Comment: it s the response i get when the trigger is executed at the backend ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I used a select statement inside trigger... Later on removed it & 
 it works fine now..

Does procedure (call value(new.od_id,@e))  have a select statement in it...